# Connected to a group coordinator but can't connect to kafka node

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I'm trying to setup an integration test where I have a kafka producer (quarkus / standard kafkaproducer, dockerized) who is pushing stuff to a topic, then my application (quarkus / reactive messaging, also dockerized) receives it and push to another topic to notify it has received the message (topic:messageReceived). And in my test I have a KafkaContainer

```
@Container
static KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.4"))
        .withNetworkAliases("kafkaNode")
        .withNetwork(CommonNetwork.getInstance())
        .withExposedPorts(9092, 9093);
```

Both my dockerized app are working great since they all share the same network, the sending/receiving/sending scenario is working. But I'm having trouble with the KafkaConsumer in my actual test who is supposed to check the topic messageReceived for a message from my app. I am using the following to add the bootstrap server config to my consumer which seems to be working :

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafka.getBootstrapServers());
```

It discovers the group coordinator with the random ip from testcontainers so the config must be correct.

```
Discovered group coordinator localhost:49725 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
```

But then it tries to connect to the following :

```
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

When it should be connecting to localhost:49725 same as the group coordinator as I only have one node which is acting as broker and group coordinator if I understood correctly.

I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't figure out what. Could use some help on the matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while exploring TestContainers for integration test. I managed to solve it with below code:

```java
KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3"));
        kafkaContainer.setPortBindings(Arrays.asList("9092:9092", "9093:9093", "2181:2181"));
        kafkaContainer.start();
        kafkaContainer.waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());
```

The KafkaConsumer was connected using:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093");
```

The key here is `PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that would probably solve my issue but I was hoping for something that wouldn't require to bind ports manually. From what I read it's not a good practice and could cause issues on CI environment because these ports might be taken.

Comment: Ok. So you can have your own logic to get the port out of this `kafka.getBootstrapServers()` and then use `PLAINTEXT://localhost:<PORT>`